# CIS based Compliance check for Ubuntu 22.04 using OpenSCAP

Tags: 22.04

We are working on implementing Hardening and Compliance check for Windows and Linux family OS. We are following OpenSCAP for Linux family OS. Presently we are working on implementing same for Ubuntu 22.04. We are referring CIS Benchmark Level 1 Server configurations.

For Ubuntu 20.04, to get compliance report, we use below command -

```
sudo oscap xccdf eval --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_cis_level1_server --results-arf arf.xml --report $1 /usr/share/ubuntu-scap-security-guides/1/benchmarks/ssg-ubuntu2004-ds.xml
```

We are looking for similar command for Ubuntu 22.04 as well. Please advise if we can get some direction in this area.
Thanks

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.x = 22.04

Comment: In our case, its 22.04 specific

Comment: why would the command be different between 20.04/20.10/22.04/22.10? See https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/oscap.8.html

Comment: sure, I will go through it.